# DropDown Selected Value Show in Menu

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have the below dropdown menu in my code. (Bootstrap5) And I want to show which member was selected instead of "Year" How can I do that?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Year
    </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/2022">2022</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2021</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2020</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I answered anyway but this question could be improved - try to format your code and give more exact details as to what you want

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a little bit of JS - on each of the dropdown elements you'll want to add an onclick to each one which triggers a simple function that gets the value of the date and then sets the button's innerText to that date.

```
<div class="dropdown show">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="yearButton" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Year
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="selectYear(2022)">2022</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="selectYear(2021)">2021</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="selectYear(2020)">2020</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  function selectYear(year) {
    const yearButton = document.getElementById('yearButton')
    yearButton.innerText = year
  }
</script>
```